# MySQL - Count distinct number of name instances in database

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

A column in my table contains names. I created a query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) Number, (b_concat_name) Name FROM `js_b_table` GROUP by Name
```

that produces the following:

```
Number | Name
1      | Chris Smith
4      | Fred Savage
2      | Sarah McArthur
```

How can I update the column **b_name_count** in **js_b_table** that contains the corresponding name (**b_concat_name**) in that row?

Comment: Whhat does this mean: "How can I dynamically update the original row, in another column, with the count from the view?" Did you mean table instead of column? What is the "original" row? Can you give a specific example?

Comment: can you provide the table and view create statements?

Comment: Yeah this question is really unclear it sounds like you're asking for several different things depending on which sentence I read

Comment: Sorry, I don't work with SQL that often. I'll try to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want `js_b_table` to look something like this:

```
b_concat_name | b_name_count | ... other fields ...
--------------+--------------+---------------------
fred          | 3            | ... other values ...
fred          | 3            | ... other values ...
fred          | 3            | ... other values ...
barney        | 2            | ... other values ...
barney        | 2            | ... other values ...
```

where every record's `b_name_count` indicates the total number of records with the same `b_concat_name`. Is that correct?

If so, you can use this:

```
UPDATE js_b_table AS jbt1
 INNER
  JOIN ( SELECT jbt2.b_concat_name,
                COUNT(*) AS b_name_count
           FROM js_b_table AS jbt2
          GROUP
             BY jbt2.b_concat_name
       ) AS jbt3
    ON jbt3.b_concat_name = jbt1.b_concat_name
   SET jbt1.b_name_count = jbt3.b_name_count
;
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I'm trying to accomplish. Unfortunately the query generates this error: #1093 - You can't specify target table 'jbt1' for update in FROM clause

Comment: @Mark: Darn it, sorry. That's an annoying limitation of MySQL. Other DBMSes are smarter. Anyway, I've edited my answer to give a statement that will work in MySQL. Sorry for not testing it to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

To get a count of how many time each name is in the table it's:

```
SELECT 
    count(*) AS number,
    name
FROM USERS
GROUP BY name
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to update a column, say name_count, for each user. You can do this by executing the following query:

```
UPDATE USERS u
SET u.name_count = 
                   (SELECT count(*)
                    FROM USERS u2 
                    WHERE u2.name = u.name);
```